# When having the cursor move from one spot to another, once it reaches its final destination the cursor doesnt detect that its over a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, tween

Imagine when a cursor is on a normal part of the page its in the normal state however when its meant to click a button it is in the ready state. Basically theres a button on the screen that I am trying to click however if i have the cursor go immediately to where the button is the cursor remains in the normal state so its unable to click the button. To try to solve this I implemented tweening from a part of the screen that isnt on the button until it gets to the button along with some side to side jitters however the cursor still ends up being in the normal state. If i move my mouse manually over the button even the tiniest movement will make the cursor go into the ready state and make the button clickable. How can i make it so that the cursor will be able to click the button automatically without having me move the cursor myself?

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random

# Define constants
BREAKTHROUGH_COLOR = (248, 248, 248)
WAIT_TIME_INITIAL = 10
WAIT_TIME_BREAKTHROUGH = 20
WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_CLICKS = 0.1

# Initial mouse position
INITIAL_POSITION = (956, 644)

# Meditate button position
MEDITATE_POSITION = (960, 980)

def tween_to_position(start_position, end_position, tween_time):
    x_start, y_start = start_position
    x_end, y_end = end_position
    
    steps = int(tween_time / 0.05)  # Number of steps based on a 0.05s interval
    
    for step in range(steps):
        progress = step / steps
        x = x_start + int((x_end - x_start) * progress)
        y = y_start + int((y_end - y_start) * progress)
        
        # Add small random jitters to the left and right
        x += random.randint(-5, 5)
        
        pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration=0.05)

def common_actions():
    # Common actions button position
    COMMON_ACTIONS_POSITION = (150, 20)
    
    # Tweening
    tween_to_position(COMMON_ACTIONS_POSITION, (75, 20), tween_time=2)
    
    time.sleep(1)  # Add a delay before the click
    pyautogui.click(75, 20, clicks=3, interval=WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_CLICKS)

while True:
    time.sleep(WAIT_TIME_INITIAL)

    if pyautogui.pixel(*INITIAL_POSITION) == BREAKTHROUGH_COLOR:
        print("Breakthrough ready")
        
        # Tweening for the breakthrough button
        tween_to_position((956, 400), INITIAL_POSITION, tween_time=2)
        
        pyautogui.click(*INITIAL_POSITION, clicks=5, interval=WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_CLICKS)  # Increase the number of clicks
        print("Waiting for breakthrough")
        time.sleep(WAIT_TIME_BREAKTHROUGH)
        print("Meditating")
        
        # Tweening for the meditation button
        tween_to_position((960, 900), MEDITATE_POSITION, tween_time=2)
        
        pyautogui.click(*MEDITATE_POSITION, clicks=5, interval=WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_CLICKS)  # Increase the number of clicks

    else:
        print("Not ready")
        common_actions()
```

I've tried many things. I tried having the point where the cursor is meant to click be on the edge of the button then making the cursor go in a circle and end up at the edge of the button to try to make it work. I tried adding a random squiggle from one location of the screen to the button. I've tried using a sine wave to make the cursor move in an S like pattern to the position of the button. I've tried moving the cursor more linearly. I've tried micro movements over the button. None of these solutions seemed to fix the problem I'm facing of having the cursor not register that it is hovering over the button. I would really appreciate any help you could provide me. Thank you

Comment: The cursor has no idea whether it's sitting above a clickable area or not.  All you can do is send a click event to the control at the cursor's location.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: Please start by creating **as simple an example as possible** that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.